How can I copy and paste a value from a column to the same column
I am trying to take a value in a column. (An ID) and paste that same value in all the rest of the rows in that column that are null (the ID is missing).  Can someone explain how I can do that? Thx
UPDATE [Andy's_Cleanup_Database].[dbo].[Implementation_Results]
SET [Client Account ID] = [Client Account ID]
    WHERE [Client Account ID] is not null

--  your textThis doesnt work.  I have also tried it using a SELECT statement like this:
UPDATE [Andy's_Cleanup_Database].[dbo].[Implementation_Results] 
SET [Client Account ID] = (SELECT [Client Account ID] FROM [dbo].[Implementation_Results]     WHERE[Client Account ID] is not null)
    WHERE [Client Account ID] is null


In what way does your second query not work?

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.

So there is more than one non-null [Client Account ID] value in your database. If they're all the same, then you could change the subquery to (SELECT DISTINCT [Client Account ID] FROM [dbo].[Implementation_Results] WHERE[Client Account ID] is not null) and that will give one result. If there is more than one unique value, you need to figure out which one you want to use to fill the NULL values with.

Please add a tag for the DBMS you're using, and share what you mean by "doesnt work". Add all clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section
